# Link two different if statements to same value (mysql query)

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have two if statements on two different columns that determine that value that I wanna display in a third virtual column. Something like:

```
if(column1 = 'activated'){
    return 15;
}

if(colunm2 = 1){
    return 'enabled';
}
```

I want to display the return values in a virtual column called let's say output in a select query. Something like:

```
SELECT IF(column1 = 'activated', 15, [what do i put here...]), 
       IF(column2 = 1, 'enabled', [what do i put here]) ..... AS consent
```

Obviously the above query doesn't work cause I can't separate my ifs with a comma since they have to be bound to the same column called (output).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are the other scenarios? If `column1 != 'activated'` and `column2 != 1`, what's the value of `column3`? Edit your question to detail every permutation.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your `if` example is returning incompatible types, so it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Post sample data and the desired result.

Comment: What do you want to return if `column1 = 'activated' AND column2 = 1`? What about if `column1 != 'activated' AND column2 != 1`? Your question doesn't describe those possibilities...

Comment: I have a feeling a union would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a `case` expression:

```
select (case when column1 = 'activated' then '15'
             when column2 = 1 then 'enabled'
        end) as consent
```